# Disable touch outside of the Bluetooth system Alert - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, bluetooth

I am new in android development.

I have a `BluetoothAdapter`, if bluetooth not enabled automatically asks the window for allow/deny. It is woking fine but, when tap on outside of the alert will dismiss the alert. How can I disable the dismissal of the alert when tap out side of the alert window.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an `Activity`, so you should call `setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)` from your activity if you want to keep your dialog open when the background activity is clicked.

Comment: How can I apply the 'setFinishOnTouchOutside' for bluetooth intent ?

Comment: `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: I have added the same in onCreate  but, still the alert is dismissing while tap outside.